# Splunk query returns 0 after using eval function

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Query return 0 value for eval calculation.

index=* platform=PC browser_name=chrome OR browser_name=edge OR browser_name=safari | stats count(eval(player_event="play")) AS Play count(eval(error_event_type="vsf")) AS VSF count(eval((Play / VSF))) AS Rate by browser_name

I would expect this query return % rate of eval counts and display a timechart

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would encourage you to review [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question after you have a chance to clarify it better.

Answer (score 0):

The Rate field cannot be calculated because Play and VSF are still being computed.  Try breaking Rate into a separate `eval` command.

```
index=* platform=PC browser_name=chrome OR browser_name=edge OR browser_name=safari 
| stats count(eval(player_event="play")) AS Play count(eval(error_event_type="vsf")) AS VSF by browser_name
| eval Rate=round(Play / VSF, 3)
```

This query cannot display a timechart because there is no _time field in the results.  To get an hourly timechart, try this.  Change `span=1h` to something else if you want a different time period in the chart.

```
index=* platform=PC browser_name=chrome OR browser_name=edge OR browser_name=safari 
| bucket span=1h _time
| stats count(eval(player_event="play")) AS Play count(eval(error_event_type="vsf")) AS VSF by time, browser_name
| eval Rate=round(Play / VSF, 3)
| timechart span=1h values(Rate) as Rate
```